# Recommended way redirect to login page on failed auth when using StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm using Nancy.Authentication.Stateless 1.4.1 and need to know what is the recommended way of issuing a redirect to a login page whenever the user is not authorized.

Currently, the authentication works in that it returns a 401 to the client.  I want to be able to intercept the 401 (server side) and instead send the user to the login page.

I can see that this is possible with Forms Authentication as stated here (https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-authentication)

**Snippet (for Forms Authentication)**

```
var formsAuthConfiguration =
new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration()
{
    RedirectUrl = "~/login",
    UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>(),
};
```

Just a bit stumped on how to do this when using StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually implement this in a custom handler for the After pipeline (see [The Application Before After and OnError pipelines](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before%2C-After-and-OnError-pipelines)) or a module's After hook (see [The before and after hooks](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks)) that will replace the response with a redirect response it it is unauthorized.

To enable it at the application level, you can use something like this:

```
pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(RedirectUnauthorizedRequests);
```

where the `RedirectUnauthorizedRequests` method could look something like this:

```cs
private static Action<NancyContext> RedirectUnauthorizedRequests()
{
    return context =>
    {
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            context.Response = context.GetRedirect("/login");
        }
    };
}
```